# What's the proper name for a set of random unique numeric strings?

Tags: terminology

Let's say I have a set of random strings, each one composed of digits, and they're all unique (the set doesn't contain duplicate values). Also, their lengths are equal. Is there a special name for that kind of sets ?
Here's an example of such a set:

```
815794
276953
412097
809762
436027
046371
640251
820516
715490
024368
680427
815367
683715
834275
194827
213968
745816
156437
807519
```

Answer (score 0):

You could call this a subset of $\{0,1,\dots,9\}^6$. I don't believe there is a special name for such sets.